# Resize Formula Bar in Excel 2003

Tags: c#, vsto

I have created an VSTO application and looking for something to set height of formula bar.
This option is available for Excel 2007 but i am unable to find any such property which could help me out for 2003 version of excel.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think there is not option available for excel 2003 to set formula bar height.

Comment: Application.FormulaBarHeight works with excel 2003 as well. Please let me know if I got you wrongly.

Comment: @gee'K'iran : that's the option available in 2007 or above version of excel but not in excel 2003

Comment: @TusharChhabhaiya: I have tested for excel 2003, which is working fine. If possible can you post your block of code?

Comment: Hi Rohit, can you post your recent updates.

Comment: @gee'K'iran I am also unable to find Application.FormulaBarHeight property in 2003 VSTO Application but the same can be found on 2007 application..We need to find something different to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

The [Application.FormulaBarHeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841264.aspx)  Property was added in Excel 2007 and is not available in earlier versions.

Comment: Yes that i have already found and mentioned this in the question itself which i have raised..My point is their any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Sorry, I realize is must be unfortunate to need this with Excel 2003. There is an awful workaround [here](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/553432-change-height-of-the-formula-bar-in-excel.html) - if you could call it that. In your software requirements perhaps add a note about support with Excel versions prior to 2007.